# How to manage user database which is present in a single database among multiple applications

Tags: mongodb, authentication

We have user data which is present in a single mongoDB. Multiple applications are using this database for user authentication.

The current method for the authentication is when the user signs in any application for the first time, data is fetched from parentDB and saved it respective local application db. The flaw with this method is when the user gets altered in parentDB, local copy needs to be synced.

Another method that we tried was writing the model definition in all the applications and connecting to parentDB of which the flaw is changing the model definition in all the applications if their is any change

What would be the suggested method for maintaining such user management ?

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think you don't need to update models in the first scenario and why you need to update them in the second one?

Comment: @AlexBlex saving it in application specific redis for now. We are storing it as string and then parsing it. So not using any models in first method

Comment: And what happens when you update the model in the "parentDB"? Do you update your parser?

Answer (score 0):

I would move authentication to separate server connected to parent db, and make all user management also request authentication server. Can also proxy authentication from app server to authentication server, so from outside it still looks like each app has its own auth.